# How to disable or turn off swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, rest

I create a project by using .Net web Api, and when I run the project, swagger appears.

Is there way to delete or turn off?

Thanks

Comment: Have you investigated the Nuget references in your project, or the contents of your Startup.cs file?

Comment: If ur asking for disabling the auto-opening browser after build, you can disable it. Click on the small triangle right to the "IIS Express" build button, click on debug properties, deselect "launch browser" option.

Answer (score 3):

You could remove all the Swagger references in your `Startup.cs` file, but all that will do is remove swagger and not the actual browser window.

If it's a console window you want, you can instead change the debug profile from IIS `Express` to `YourProjectName`.

It's under the little dropdown button next to the Execute button.

**Note**: Just make sure that the profile doesn't launch the browser when debugging. To check if it's off, navigate to: `Project > Properties > Debug`, select your `Profile` and make sure the `Launch browser` checkbox is turned off.